# Switching between different layouts for same content (InDesign)

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, print-production

For each page of a magazine, the content is the same: 1-2 photos, article content, title, subtitle, and author name. There are also four different layouts: three column full, three column with header, two column, and section header.

Now lets say I have an article (with all of the content information mentioned) and I realize that it won't fit into the "three column full" layout. How can I, in the fewest clicks possible, switch to a two column layout.

In my dream world I would be able to: label different text boxes with different names (say "author" and "article content") and then be able to switch layouts so that all of the content is transferred to the correct text box in the new layout.

What's the best way to do this? If it's completely impossible, what are some alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation required to post a comment, but I'm wondering if you're using master pages for these layouts and if your content is tagged with the needed paragraph styles. If so, then you as long as all the content is in the primary text frame, it should convert nicely when you apply a different master to the page. I believe more detail on your process is needed to be able to answer this question.

Comment: I guess I don't have a good understanding of more advanced master page features. I thought they could only set things like the background/headers/footers

Comment: Master pages can be a powerful, efficient, and even flexible framework for your documents. There are people who use InDesign extensively without making use of master pages or styles (paragraph, character, object). But using them is a time and sanity saver, especially when more than just one person is accessing the file. The links I provided regarding master pages in your other recent question (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57022/indesign-create-new-page-from-template/57103#57103) are good starting places. Also, check out InDesignSecrets.com. It's another great resource.

Comment: you should have the reputation now.